# Google Fit SDK Returns Dataset with Empty DataPoints

Tags: android, google-fit

I have issues with the Google Fit SDK, in which I was trying to get the steps history from the SDK. While I do see the number of buckets being returned including the datasets. However all datasets does not contained any data points at all, even though the Steps Counter on my Google Fit App was listed there.

Here is my code.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(new Locale("en", "US", "POSIX"));
    calendar.setTime(Utilities.generateDate(new Date(), Utilities.DATE_FORMAT_F));
    long endTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
    long startTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

    DataSource ESTIMATED_STEP_DELTAS = new DataSource.Builder()
            .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .setType(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
            .setStreamName("estimated_steps")
            .setAppPackageName("com.google.android.gms")
            .build();
    DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .aggregate(ESTIMATED_STEP_DELTAS,    DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
            .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .enableServerQueries()
            .build();


    Fitness.getHistoryClient(mContext, account)
            .readData(readRequest)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DataReadResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DataReadResponse dataReadResponse) {
                    printData(dataReadResponse);
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onFailure()", e);
                }
            })
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataReadResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataReadResponse> task) {
                    printData(task.getResult());
                }
            });
```

Hence, I was wondering which part of the Google Fit SDK that I missed.
Any help would be appreciated. Additionally, please note that I do subscribe the Google Fit SDK and my Google Fit App has the Steps History actually.

Thank you.

Comment: `calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);` what does this return?

Comment: I have the same problem, what was your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your request from

```
DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .aggregate(ESTIMATED_STEP_DELTAS, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
            .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .enableServerQueries()
            .build();
```

to

```
DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
            .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .enableServerQueries()
            .build();
```

i.e Instead of passing datasource pass the datatype.